# PHPExcel FatalError on reading cell with formula

Tags: phpexcel

I read file cell by cell with getCalculatedValue(). 
When I read cell with the wrong formula I get Fatal Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception' with
>   message 'Лист1!B291 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured' in
>   /PHPExcel/Cell.php:300 Stack trace: #0 /class_phpexcel.php(1145):
>   PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue()

Is there a way to avoid the Fatal Error and simply ignore the value of a cell?

Link to file: [problem-cell-b291.xlsx](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8389605/problem-cell-b291.xlsx) (problem with cell **B291**)

Code:

```
require_once 'class_phpexcel.php';
$E = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('problem-cell-b291.xlsx');
$E->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, 291)->getCalculatedValue();
```

Comment: `When I read cell with the __wrong__ formula I get Fatal Error:`... so what do you think PHPExcel should do when it reads a cell with a wrong formula? What should it return, that couldn't be misinterpreted as a valid value?

Comment: But as PHPExcel actually throws an Exception, you can wrap the call in a try/catch block, and handle the exception yourself however you consider appropriate.... you're getting a Fatal error because your'e not catching the exception, so catch it

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will use try/catch.

Comment: I think there is no need to interrupt the script with a fatal error, you can instead give out an error code, which I can understand what the problem is. Sorry for my english.

Comment: PHPExcel doesn't interrupt the script with a fatal error; it throws an Exception; that's pretty standard approach to returning an error situation from many libraries. An Exception is not a fatal error; it's how PHPExcel informs your script that it has an error condition. It's up to the calling script to handle Exceptions, and an Exception that isn't handled is what results in a fatal error

Comment: And a call to `getCalculatedValue()` can result in valid returns of `null`, `false`, `0`, `''`, etc; so how else could `getCalculatedValue()` indicate that it had errored? What error code could it return?

Comment: It seems logical behavior by analogy with MS Excel to show `#REF!` in this cell. I was expecting something like that.

Comment: The PHPExcel Exception is a lot more flexible, in that you can control exactly what is done when it is thrown, but it's thrown when PHPExcel is incapable of evaluating the formula due to an exceptional circumstance; whereas `#REF!` is returned when an formula results in a condition that isn't exceptional, and can be trapped using MS Excel functions such as `IS_ERROR()`

Comment: But if you dislike the way PHPExcel works, it's open source, so your'e' welcome too change it for yourself

Comment: Ok, Mark. Thanks!